# How to solve this question from MIT 18.02 multi-variable calc about contour plots?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is from MIT OCW's Multivariable Calculus:

[image]

I understand that we need to be marking somewhere on the level curve f = 2000 here, but other than that, I'm unsure how to decide which portion of that level curve has $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \geq 0$.

Comment: *Hint*: What does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ mean?  (Think back to beginning of one-variable calculus.)  There are some reasonable assumptions you need to make on $f$.

Comment: Hint: the altitude must increase when you walk north.

Comment: @user10354138 it means how $f$ varies as $y$ varies. So it's the region of level curve $f=2000$ that's pointing to the centre of the concentric circle but from in a north-wise fashion?